# radNotification not work with updatepanel

Tags: telerik

I am using telerik control and radNotification not displaying text when m trying to keep the page content in updatepanel.if i dont keep the content in update panel then radnotification is working
Please help how radnotification work with update panel

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="BasicInformation" runat="server">

    <telerik:RadNotification ID="notification" runat="server" Position="Center"
        TitleIcon="~/Images/warn.gif" ContentIcon="~/Images/warn.gif"
        AutoCloseDelay="0"  Width="350" EnableRoundedCorners="true">
    </telerik:RadNotification>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CFC Order To Supplier</legend>
        <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxpanel1" runat="server">

            <table><tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><telerik:RadButton ID="btn_submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="btn_submit_Click"></telerik:RadButton></td>
            </tr></table>
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    </fieldset>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RadNotification` inside the `RadAjaxPanel`. By doing this user text will be displayed 
like this.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxpanel1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadNotification ID="notification" runat="server" 
        Position="Center" 
        TitleIcon="~/Images/warn.gif" 
        ContentIcon="~/Images/warn.gif"
        AutoCloseDelay="0" 
        Width="350" 
        EnableRoundedCorners="true">
    </telerik:RadNotification>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="btn_submit" runat="server" 
                    Text="Submit" 
                    onclick="btn_submit_Click">
                </telerik:RadButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the text once you should use the Show(newText) method (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/servershowwithnewtext/defaultcs.aspx). This does not require that you update the control with AJAX. Besides, the notification already uses callbacks and wrapping them in AJAX requests kind of makes their performance gain a moot point.